# Struggling with table relations in mysql database

Tags: mysql, database-design

Let's say I have a parent table and a child table with parent_is as foreign key. Now I want to store photos that could either belong to parent or child. so I could have a parent_id and a child_id foreign keys in the photos table: when the photo belongs to parent then the child_id foreign key column would be null and vice-versa. But instead of that I decided to go for a different design: I now have a `item` table and I get the `parent` table primary key (`parent_id`) to also be foreign key referencing the `item_id` column in the `item` table, and the `child` table primary key (`child_id`) also as a foreign key to the same `item_id` column in the `item` table. So now instead of having two different foreign keys ( referencing to `child_id` and `parent_id`) in my `photos` table I only have one (referencing to `item_id`):

```
CREATE TABLE `parent` (
    `parent_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`parent_id`),
     CONSTRAINT `parent_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) 
     REFERENCES `item` (`item_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)


CREATE TABLE `child` (
    `child_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`child_id`),
     CONSTRAINT `child_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`child_id`) 
     REFERENCES `item` (`item_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)


CREATE TABLE `item` (
    `item_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`))

CREATE TABLE `photo` (
    `photo_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `item_id` int(10)unsigned NOT NULL, 
    `name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`photo_id`),
     CONSTRAINT `photo_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`item_id`) 
     REFERENCES `item` (`item_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

I hope that's clear so far! So that works but now my problem is if I want to delete a `parent` record: I would delete the corresponding `item_id` record in the `item` table which would automatically delete the corresponding record in the `parent` table thanks to the foreign key, which then would automatically delete the records in the `child` table belonging to that parent. All good except that I would be left with the records in the `item` table corresponding to the child records that have just been deleted. The `item` table would not know that some child records have been deleted unless the `item_id` in the `item` table was also a foreign key referencing the corresponding `child_id` in the `child` table. I've got the feeling my design is wrong? What would be the recommended design in that case?

Comment: Dup of http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/155765/how-to-design-parent-child-photos-relationships-in-mysql-when-photos-can-belon

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a direct tie between parent and child in your design; so "automatically delete the records in the child table belonging to that parent" isn't automatic, since there is no direct relationship between them. The relationship I see, is that the delete on item will delete all rows that use the same key value in both parent and child, and also in photo.